# How to Compare Mismatched Data between Two Tables and Show Them in A Row in Oracle Database or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables in Oracle Database. One containing temporary data and other containing permanent data. I want to compare them and see which column data has a mismatch between them for the same unique id.

Here are the two table:

**BRIDGE_FINAL:**

```
BRIDGE_ID    MATERIAL_ID HEIGHT WIDTH THICKNESS
dff12cd6     4           0      0     0
15b54528     4           0      0     0
486a0aa7     4           0      0     0
2ae64f7b     1           0      0     0
2acf7e37     1           0      0     0
5e7baef5     1           0      0     0
```

**BRIDGE_TEMP:**

```
BRIDGE_ID    MATERIAL_ID HEIGHT WIDTH THICKNESS
dff12cd6     4           5      0     0
15b54528     4           6      7     9
486a0aa7     4           0      0     0
2ae64f7b     1           0      0     0
2acf7e37     1           0      0     0
5e7baef5     1           0      0     0
```

I want to show exactly which columns have mismatched value for same BRIDGE_ID, with both column values side by side

**MY EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
BRIDGE_ID    COLUMN_NAME FINAL_VALUE TEMP_VALUE
dff12cd6     HEIGHT      0           5
15b54528     HEIGHT      0           6
15b54528     WIDTH       0           7
15b54528     THICKNESS   0           9
```

**I need to do it in Oracle database. But if this can be done in ASP.NET MVC in code, it will also do.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simulated your example in the following queries:

```
create table final_value(bridge_id varchar(40), material_id int, height int, width int, thickness int);

create table temp_value(bridge_id varchar(40), material_id int, height int, width int, thickness int);

insert into final_value values ('dff12cd6',4,0,0,0),('15b54528',4,0,0,0),('486a0aa7',4,0,0,0);

insert into temp_value values ('dff12cd6',4,5,0,0),('15b54528',4,6,7,9),('486a0aa7',4,0,0,0);


select a.bridge_id as 'Bridge ID', a.measure_name AS 'Measure Name', a.final_val as 'Final Value', ISNULL(b.temp_val, 0) as 'Temp Value ' from
(select bridge_id,
  measure_name,
  final_val
from final_value
unpivot
(
  final_val
  for measure_name in (height, width, thickness)
) unpiv) a

left join

(select bridge_id,
  measure_name,
  temp_val
from temp_value
unpivot
(
  temp_val
  for measure_name in (height, width, thickness)
) unpiv) b

on
a.bridge_id = b.bridge_id and
a.measure_name = b.measure_name;
```

you can also refer the same from rextester here: https://rextester.com/WFHO83710

Comment: Can you please mark it as answer if it worked? Thanks